# TCP Connection is alive when I cut the network on OSX and iOS

Tags: ios, macos, sockets, tcp

I write a simple TCP client use socket, and send heartbeats to a TCP server for connection detective. when I cut my network, the heartbeats is ok util receive timeout on OSX and iOS. I test the same scenario on Android, I get a send error just after I cut the network. sample code snippet here:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<std::thread> ThreadPtr;
int server_socket;
// thread for send something.
ThreadPtr create_send_thread(const std::string& content) {
    ThreadPtr thread(new std::thread([&]() {
        std::string msg;
        while (true) {
            int ret = send(server_socket, content.c_str(),
                           content.size(), 0);
            if (ret == -1) {
                perror("SEND failed!\n");
            }
            printf("SEND %s\n", msg.c_str());
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(
                std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
    }));
    return thread;
}
// thread for receive data.
ThreadPtr create_recv_thread() {
    ThreadPtr thread(new std::thread([]() {
        char recv_msg[1024];
        while (true) {
            bzero(recv_msg, 1024);
            long byte_num = recv(server_socket, recv_msg, 1024, 0);
            if (byte_num <= 0) {
                perror("RECV failed!");
            } else {
                std::string msg(recv_msg, byte_num);
                prinf("RECV %s", msg.c_str());
            }
        }
    }));
    return thread;
}
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(8000);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket == -1) {
        perror("socket error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int ret = connect(server_socket,
                      (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                      sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (ret == 0) {
        ThreadPtr pt0 = create_send_thread("heartbeats");
        ThreadPtr pt1 = create_recv_thread();
        pt0->join();
        pt1->join();      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any method for detect net break immediately on OSX and iOS not util receive timeout, just like Android?

Comment: This is very platform-specific.  Depending on HOW the network is getting cut off, the OS may or may not be able to notify active peers right away.  You can't depend on this behavior in a cross platform manner.  Rely on timeouts only.  If needed, enable TCP-level keepalives to help detect lost connections sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to network program. I don't know how to enable TCP-level keepalives, can you provide some sample to do this?

Comment: use `setsockopt()` with the `SOL_SOCKET` `SO_KEEPALIVE` option, and the `IPPROTO_TCP` `TCP_KEEPALIVE` option.

Comment: Thanks. I will try.